# Regular Express to Grab first dollar amount

Tags: javascript, regex, regression

Looking out first $ Symbols amount

**$647.50 (Save $94)**`tried this code regular express`: .match(/$(\d+)/);

But Does not working

OutPut Looking

647.50

Comment: Clearly you are expecting a dot in your regular expression.

Answer (score -1):

```
[$](\d+).(\d+)
```

You have tried this it's working